# How do I join 1 column data with another column in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

[image]

I have 2 columns with Data in same table. How do I do a join to get the following result as attached in the image

Comment: Why is this tagged Oracle and some MySQL tags? They are two different RDBMS that just happen to be both owned by Oracle.

Comment: Why do you want that?

Comment: For future questions, you should type the sample data instead of using an image.  Images can disappear over time, and can't be directly copied from.  Also be sure to only tag the database you are using since many of them do things differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a [`CROSS JOIN`](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/advance-query-in-mysql/mysql-cross-join.php)

```
SELECT t.Col1, t2.Col2
FROM yourTable t
CROSS JOIN yourTable t2
```